# How to set a default value for a query that returns no rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, default, rows

I have created a trigger with a select statement and I want to say if this select statement does not return any rows then put a 0 in the variable "auxiliar". I tried to use NVL(auxiliar,0) but it does not work. How can I do this?

`SELECT NVL(salary,0) INTO auxiliar FROM BILL WHERE code=:NEW.code;`

[UPDATED] My trigger code:

```
IF preCondicio THEN
        KMpendents:=coalesce(SELECT rev_pendent_km
            INTO KMpendents
            FROM REV_PENDENT
            WHERE rev_pendent_vehicle_codi=:NEW.lloguer_vehicle_codi,0);
        IF KMtotals+KMpendents>=15000 THEN
            SELECT venedor_codi 
            INTO venedorCodi 
            FROM venedor 
            WHERE venedor_alta=(
                SELECT MAX(venedor_alta) 
                FROM venedor 
                WHERE venedor_delegacio_codi=(
                    SELECT venedor_delegacio_codi
                    FROM venedor
                    WHERE venedor_codi=:NEW.lloguer_venedor_codi));
            INSERT INTO REVISIONS VALUES(:NEW.lloguer_vehicle_codi,:NEW.lloguer_dataf,KMtotals+KMpendents,venedorCodi);
            IF KMpendents!=0 THEN
                DELETE FROM REV_PENDENT 
                WHERE rev_pendent_vehicle_codi=:NEW.lloguer_vehicle_codi;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF KMpendents!=0 THEN
                UPDATE REV_PENDENT SET rev_pendent_km=KMtotals+KMpendents WHERE rev_pendent_vehicle_codi=:NEW.lloguer_vehicle_codi;
            ELSE INSERT INTO REV_PENDENT VALUES(:NEW.lloguer_vehicle_codi,KMtotals,:NEW.lloguer_dataf);
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
```

The variable ***KMpendents*** is equivalent to the variable *auxiliar* which I told before the updated. But Oracle shows me these errors:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the
>   following: . ( * @ % & - + ; / at for mod remainder rem and or group
>   having intersect minus order start union where connect || indicator
>   multiset

Comment: dbms? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, ...?

Comment: Can you show the trigger code?

Comment: Question updated with the trigger code

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
 SELECT NVL(salary,0) INTO auxiliar FROM BILL WHERE code=:NEW.code;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NOTFOUND THEN
      auxiliar := 0;
END;
```

Or you can use `SQL%NOTFOUND` too to check if the statement returned `no rows`.

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT
   ON table_name
   [ FOR EACH ROW ]

DECLARE
   -- variable declarations

BEGIN
    ....
    ....
    BEGIN
     SELECT NVL(salary,0) INTO auxiliar FROM BILL WHERE code=:NEW.code;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NOTFOUND THEN
          auxiliar := 0;
    END;
    --Yes, this is possible and valid.

EXCEPTION
   WHEN ...
   -- exception handling

END;
```

Comment: Lose that "when others then null" ... It's a problem waiting to happen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not help me because when the trigger enters to EXCEPTION it will stop and I want the trigger to go on.

Comment: @albert you dont have to put it on the Trigger's exception, instead put the entire block in the trigger body. Updated answer

Comment: @Annjawn I did not know I can begin a process into one. That really works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the select clause contains only aggregate functions then there will always be at least one row returned.

```
SELECT coalesce(sum(salary),0)
INTO   auxiliar
FROM   BILL
WHERE  code=:NEW.code;
```

Comment: You'd best show the complete code. It works on SQL Fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c74f5/3